# I'm trying to show to mouse position on a window, but I can't update the text on the window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The text on the window stays the same as it was in the start.

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller


from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

mouse = Controller()

Label(root, text=mouse.position).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Listener for pynput:

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller
from pynput.mouse import Listener
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

root = Tk() 
mouse = Controller()

var = StringVar()
var.set(str(mouse.position))

def on_move(x, y):
    var.set(str((x,y)))

ll = Label(root, textvariable = var)

ll.pack()
with Listener(on_move=on_move) as listener:
    root.mainloop()
```

This worked for me.